# UWP - Get path to user download folder

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

I have been looking for a little while now and am not finding much help via MSDN resources and others.

My predicament is simple: my app needs a base directory to the Downloads folder. I am aware of the `DownloadsFolder` class however that is not suiting my needs currently.

How do I get the current user's Download folder path in a Windows Universal App?

Comment: `DownloadsFolder is not suiting my needs` so what are you looking for precisely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that what you need?

```
string localfolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path;
var array = localfolder.Split('\\');
var username = array[2];
string downloads = @"C:\Users\" + username + @"\Downloads";
```

This will result

> C:\Users\username\Downloads

Comment: I figured this was the solution but wasn't sure if I was overlooking a framework or class in NETCore that would already be provided. Thank you!

Comment: This is a static, bad practice solution. It relies on the filesystem not changing, this is more elegant: UserDataPaths.GetDefault().Downloads

Answer (score 13):

Use [`Windows.Storage.UserDataPaths`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.userdatapaths) to get the path of user's download folder.

```
string downloadsPath = UserDataPaths.GetDefault().Downloads;
```

- This method is introduced in build 16232, so clients with RS3(1709) or later will be able to run it.
- You shouldn't obtain downloads folder path using LocalFolder, which might result in wrong folder when the user [changed the default location for it](https://www.howtogeek.com/273618/how-do-you-change-windows-default-download-path/).

Comment: This is more reliable answer!

Answer (score 4):

```
System.Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%userprofile%/downloads/")
```

Answer (score 0):

The `DownloadsFolder` for an app now defaults to a folder withing the user's Downloads directory named after the app name (in actual fact the app name folder is simply a link to a folder named after the `Package Family Name`)
To get the folder name, I used the following hack (vb) to first create a dummy file in the UWP app's DownloadsFolder then using .NET code to get the directory name, and finally deleting the dummy file.

```
Dim o As StorageFile = Await DownloadsFolder.CreateFileAsync("dummy.txt", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName)
Dim dirName Ss String = Path.GetDirectoryName(o.Path)
Await o.DeleteAsync(StorageDeleteOption.PermanentDelete)
```