# UWP : Get the current UserName to provide rights to the user

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, account

For an app that I develop for a customer, I need to get the current user details.
Then I must assign rights by comparing the couple "**domain\login**" to a table containing all the authorized users.

I reuse the code given by @Sergiu Cojocaru [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33394019/get-username-in-a-windows-10-c-sharp-uwp-universal-windows-app/33395034#33395034) , that I have mixed with an official sample ([UserInfo](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/UserInfo)) to get more details:

```
IReadOnlyList<Windows.System.User> users = await Windows.System.User.FindAllAsync();

var current = users.Where(u => u.AuthenticationStatus == Windows.System.UserAuthenticationStatus.LocallyAuthenticated &&
                               u.Type == Windows.System.UserType.LocalUser).FirstOrDefault();

// user may have username
var data = await current.GetPropertyAsync(KnownUserProperties.AccountName);
string displayName = (string)data;

// or may be authenticated using hotmail/outlook
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(displayName))
{
    string firstName = (string)await current.GetPropertyAsync(KnownUserProperties.FirstName);
    string lastName = (string)await current.GetPropertyAsync(KnownUserProperties.LastName);
    displayName = string.Format("{0} {1}", firstName, lastName);
}
```

But actually I  only get the "**firstName**" and the "**lastName**" from "**KnownUserProperties**". The others properties are empties:

- providerName: null
- accountName: null
- guestHost: null
- principalName: null
- domainName: null
- sipUri: null

***=> Is this normal?***

The problem is that the expected couple "**domain\login**" is based on the result of the command line "**whoami**", that doesn't give the same result that "**firstName**" and "**lastName**".

***=> Is there a way to get the same result in the app?***

I specify that I use a hotmail account but the customers accounts must be based on Active Directory: I don't know if this will change anything...

Comment: if you want to take the username for the user, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39949829/uwp-get-path-to-user-download-folder/39972084#39972084

Comment: Thanks but that's not really what I need, as this only gives the username, but not the domain...

Comment: For domainName and sipUri I can got on my side. Did you join a domain?

Comment: I didn't join a domain, but the problem is that I need to use the same format of data that are recovered through "whoami" command line.

Answer (score 0):

To get information about domain and domain user change

```
var data = await current.GetPropertyAsync(KnownUserProperties.AccountName);
```

to

```
var data = await current.GetPropertyAsync(KnownUserProperties.DomainName);
```

on my side result is:
ROM.EUROPE.TECHTEAM.COM\scojocar

Comment: Thanks @Sergiu Cojocaru.
But as I have mentioned in my first post, I have also tried to use the solution given in the UserInfo sample: all available properties of KnownUserProperties have been recovered, but only FirstName and LastName have a value.
I wonder if that is not cause I use a personal Outlook account to log me in to Windows. Will it be different with an Active Directory account, as the final customer must use these?

Comment: if you use it personal account you'll have firstname and lastname filled with your data, when you're on a domain, your firstname and lastname will be empty and only DomainName property will contain data about your domainname and username

Comment: So the result is normal? But how can retriver the "host" details that I can get with the command line "whoami", wich gives me: "host\username"?

Comment: see https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/apps/windows.security.exchangeactivesyncprovisioning.easclientdeviceinformation.friendlyname.aspx: new Windows.Security.ExchangeActiveSyncProvisioning.EasClientDeviceInformation().friendlyName;